# Session hijacking

Tags: authentication, http, javascript, access-control

I know one way of doing session hijacking

1.copying the session value from the chrome browser and pasting the cookie value to firefox browser

Is there any other way of doing session hijacking ? If yes please share the process of doing session hijacking.

Answer (score 6):

I think your question is a bit too broad.

Session hijacking can be done on different levels, and it's not just copying something between browsers.  For example:

- A malicious network admin/proxy admin could intercept your session ID and re-use this also.
- A vulnerable website could be exploited using cross-site scripting, where an attacker can gain access to your document.cookie contents.
- Malicious domains, such as AD serving platforms could execute active content, such as JavaScript, and try to access your cookie information as well.
- Malware can read HTTP traffic/session information, and take this.
- Cross-site request forgery vulnerabilities could make you execute requests without you knowing, indirectly, "hijacking" your active session.
- if you're website is vulnerable to session fixation, an attacker could trick a victim to follow a link, and setting his/her session ID.  When the user logs in, the attacker knows the session information (since he's the one that set it).
- Broken session management, whereby a session ID is easily guessable.

There are many ways that an active session could be hijacked, and each will have a particular process; which is quite lengthy to explain all in one answer.